# How to resolve ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'core'. Check that 'OutilSuivisEffectifs.apps.core.apps.CoreConfig.name' is correct

Tags: python, django

my work flow:

```
OutilSuivisEffectifs
   apps
      core
        migrations
        static
        templates
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        forms.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        urls.py
        views.py
   __initi__.py
   settings.py
   urls.py
   wsgi.py
manage.py
```

my Installed apps in OutilSuivisEffectifs/settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = 
[     'django.contrib.admin',     'django.contrib.auth',     'django.contrib.contenttypes',     'django.contrib.sessions',     'django.contrib.messages',     'django.contrib.staticfiles',     'crispy_forms',     'django_countries',     'bootstrap3_datetime',     'captcha',     'OutilSuivisEffectifs.apps.core',     'import_export' ]
```

my OutilSuivisEffectifs/apps/core/apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
name = 'core'
```

the command I am running is `Python manage.py makemigrations`

The error I get

```
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\c69961\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\c69961\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
django.setup()
File "C:\Users\c69961\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Users\c69961\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "C:\Users\c69961\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 246, in create
raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'core'. Check that 'OutilSuivisEffectifs.apps.core.apps.CoreConfig.name' is correct.`
```

I tried to change name :

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
name = 'OutilSuivisEffectifs.apps.core'
```

But same error